# Matiyasevich's theorem and Gödel's first incompleteness theorem

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, computability-theory

In the Wikipedia article [Diophantine set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set) there is a section entitled "Further applications" in regards to Matiyasevich's theorem and it states:

> Matiyasevich's theorem has since been used to prove that many problems from calculus and differential equations are unsolvable.
>
> One can also derive the following stronger form of Gödel's first incompleteness theorem from Matiyasevich's result:

and then states the theorem. However, this section contains no specific citations. Could somebody provide me with references of this proof worthy of citation? Specifically, I mean the proof regarding the first incompleteness theorem. Granted, it is easy to see how Matiyasevich's theorem can prove Gödel's first incompleteness theorem, but I am looking for (possible the first) published paper with this result to be able to reference it.

Comment: The proof is a variant of the so-called "abstract form" of G's Th, due to Kleene (1950). See e.g. Stephen Cole Kleene, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=q-YEuuZ_j8EC&pg=PA246), Dover reprint (1967), page 246. Kleene's proof is base on Turing computability, but every r.e. set that is not decidable will do. 1/2

Comment: See e.g. Yuri Manin, [A Course in Mathematical Logic for Mathematicians](https://books.google.it/books?id=ftK9pUj8SaMC&pg=PR15), Springer (2010), **Ch.VI** and **VII** or Herbert Enderton, [Computability Theory: An Introduction to Recursion Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=y8n76ztNVlMC&pg=PA119), Academic Press (2011), page 119. And see Raymond Smullyan, [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](https://books.google.it/books?id=04zalcCdKZsC&pg=PA5), Oxford (1992), apge 5. 2/2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are writing a research paper on this, the usual practice in mathematics is that you do not need a reference for such an obvious result which is known to everyone in the field already.  For things like this, there is often no paper that claims credit for the result - one of the roles of books is to summarize these "well known" results that nobody would take credit for in a paper.

I suspect that the result was "first known" even before Matiyasevich proved the final part of the MDRP theorem, in the sense that everyone realized that a negative answer to Hilbert's 10th problem would lead immediately to this kind of result.

However, Martin Davis does mention this result as Theorem 7.7 of ''Hilbert's 10th problem is unsolvable'', *The American Mathematical Monthly*, 80(3), 1973, pp. 233-269.  He provides what he calls an "informal heuristic" argument, which is the standard argument sketched by Carlo Beenakker in another answer here.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for the answer

Answer (score 11):

The reference to Matiyasevich is

Matiyasevich, Y., 1970, “Diofantovost’ perechislimykh mnozhestv,” Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR, 191(2): 297–282 (Russian). (English translation, 1970, “Enumerable sets are Diophantine,” Soviet Math. Dokl., 11(2): 354–358.)

This is Matiyasevich's solution to Hilbert's 10th problem. How it can be used to obtain a proof to Gödel's first incompleteness theorem is explained by Torkel Franzén ([Gödel's Theorem: An incomplete guide to its use and abuse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568812388), 2005, page 73).

> Matiyasevich proved that there is no algorithm
>   that, given a multivariate polynomial $p(x_1, x_2,...,x_k)$ with integer
>   coefficients, determines whether there is an integer solution to the
>   equation $p = 0$. Because polynomials with integer coefficients, and
>   integers themselves, are directly expressible in the language of
>   arithmetic, if a multivariate integer polynomial equation $p = 0$ does
>   have a solution in the integers then any sufficiently strong system of
>   arithmetic $T$ will prove this. Moreover, if the system $T$ is
>   ω-consistent, then it will never prove that a particular polynomial
>   equation has a solution when in fact there is no solution in the
>   integers. Thus, if $T$ were complete and ω-consistent, it would be
>   possible to determine algorithmically whether a polynomial equation
>   has a solution by merely enumerating proofs of $T$ until either "$p$ has a
>   solution" or "$p$ has no solution" is found, in contradiction to
>   Matiyasevich's theorem.

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Relationship_with_computability)

Comment: I'm aware of what Matiyasevich's theorem is and how it can be used to prove the first incompleteness theorem. Franzen's book is a great overview of Gödel's results but what I am meaning to ask for is any paper that proves this result, not a book for non specialists. I'm writing a paper and I need a reference, I guess in particular it would be nice to know when this result was first shown.